# Push Manager - on change subscription event

Tags: typescript, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

**Question**

Is there any event I can listen to when new push subscription is added (after *subscribe()*) to browser or when the subscription is removed (after *unsubscribe()*)?

**Scenario**

I have react component in which I need update state when push subscription is added or removed in my browser scope. This subscription is added in common script which can be executed before or after my component will be mounted.

**Tries**

I tried pushsubscriptionchange where sw is *ServiceWorkerRegistration* object

```
sw.addEventListener("pushsubscriptionchange", func);
```

but it does not work at all (func never is executed).

*sw.pushManager* does not have addEventListener at all.

Answer (score 2):

pushsubscriptionchange doesn't seem to get called for me as well.. you just need to save the subscription to your api when they allow. For unsubscribes, the push api let's you know at the time you try to send, so just mark subscriptions as unsubscribed. I know it's not ideal not knowing exactly when they unsubscribed, but better than nothing

Comment: Do you know why? It is browser problem?

Comment: Honestly don't know. Chrome hasn't supported the pushsubscriptionchange event (although that may have changed in the past year), and firefox only seems to trigger on expiration or user refresh, not on removing the subscription. So yeah it's very unreliable and since I'm working on a time pressured project, I don't have the time to investigate it